# Как сделать drag&drop по сетке в js?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, drag-n-drop, javascript-events

Как сделать drag&drop как на рабочем столе, чтобы элемент, который ты перетаскиваешь вставал по нужной мне сетке на сайте. Я не могу узнать, куда нужно вставить элемент из-за того, что не знаю, откуда мне взять на него ссылку. Отрисовка не с помощью canvas, а просто grid элемент, в нём div элементы(ячейки поля), а перемещаю я другие div-ы.

Я делаю так:

-На событие mousedown элемент становится абсолютным.

-На событие mousemove элемент принимает позицию мыши.

-На событие mouseup он становится опять статичным.

Но я не могу определить, над какой клеткой происходит событие mouseup, чтобы сделать .append() элемента в эту клетку, т.к. не могу определить, что это за клетка(event.target это сам кружочек, потому что с него мы и отпустили мышь).

Comment: `document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY)` - возвращает наиболее глубоко вложенный элемент по заданным координатам окна. Здесь можно почитать https://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-drag-and-drop